# How do I reassign the F3 key to another application?

Tags: macos, expose

I have a gesture for Exposé so I need another button (the F3) to do the same. I'd love to replace F3 to show/hide the [MacBartender](http://www.macbartender.com/) app.

[image: Here's where I assign a keyboard shortcut to MacBartender]

Would it be possible to reassign this key for such a use? I have [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) installed but it does not allow for changing individual keys (I either change all my function keys or none at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/) allows you to change the function keys individually.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If you click the check button under the voting options, you'll "accept" my answer as correct. (If I remember correctly, you'll get a few reputation from doing it, too.)

Comment: Not to worry, I am a SO user myself. I couldn't do it because it was too soon and I was planning to come back anyway. ;)

Comment: Is it normal for the 'Flipped Keys' pane to not be populated? Mine says "No Special Function Keys" I am not sure how to use this program as the instructions show that list being populated in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

KeyRemap4MacBook does allow changing individual media keys.

Save something like this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>Change Expose to F19</name>
    <identifier>B83A0F12-896A-42C4-AE87-1F24EE0B989E</identifier>
    <autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::EXPOSE_ALL, KeyCode::F19</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Press the ReloadXML button and enable the remapping in the first tab.